# Aligning Columns in matplotlib.pyplot.figtext

Tags: python, matplotlib, alignment, python-3.6

(towns_n and Towns are two arrays each with 50 numbers and names respectively)

```
count = 0 
for number,town in zip(towns_n,Towns):
    textString += (number +'.'+ town).ljust(35)
    count += 1
    if count == 6:
        count = 0
        textString += '\n' 
plt.figtext(0.13,0.078,textString)
```

My problem is that I want to plot 6 columns.

And if I **print** my string it looks exactly as expected, it looks like 6 aligned columns. But if I plot it along my other image it doesn't look aligned at all.
I don't think it matters but my other image is a map usign basemap. I am plotting this string just below my map.

[What I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WSXO.png)

Edit: You can try this to generate 50 random strings and numbers so that you don't need the actual list of towns.

```
def id_generator(size=6, chars=string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits):
    return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(size))

Towns=[]
towns_n=[]

for i in range(50):
    string = id_generator()
    Towns.append(string);
    towns_n.append(str(i))
```

Comment: Can you please provide an image of what you are talking about here? Also, provide a [mcve] of the issue.

Comment: I guess what you are trying to do requires a [monospaced font](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font). Did you consider using one? Otherwise you would need to create 6 single text elements (one for each "column"). Again, provide a [mcve] to get an answer (or are you expecting someone to type in all cities in the UK?).

Comment: Thanks, I think I am about to give up and do what you suggest about the 6 strings. I have added something in the last edit so that you can get 50 random words and numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comments, one solution would be to use a [monospaced font](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font).

```
plt.figtext(..., fontname="DejaVu Sans Mono")
```

Example:

```
import random
import string
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def id_generator(size=6, chars=string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits):
    return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(size))

Towns=[]
towns_n=[]

for i in range(50):
    string = id_generator()
    Towns.append(string);
    towns_n.append(str(i))


count = 0 
textString =""
for number,town in zip(towns_n,Towns):
    textString += (number +'.'+ town).ljust(12)
    count += 1
    if count == 6:
        count = 0
        textString += '\n'

fig = plt.figure()
fig.add_subplot(111)
fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.5)
plt.figtext(0.05,0.078,textString, fontname="DejaVu Sans Mono")

plt.show()
```

[image]

The other option is to create each column separately:

```
import random
import string
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def id_generator(size=6, chars=string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits):
    return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(size))

Towns=[]
towns_n=[]

for i in range(50):
    string = id_generator()
    Towns.append(string);
    towns_n.append(str(i))


fig = plt.figure()
fig.add_subplot(111)
fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.5)

space = 0.05
left = 0.05
width= 0.15
for i in range(6):
    t = [towns_n[i::6][j] + ". " + Towns[i::6][j] for j in range(len(towns_n[i::6]))]
    t = "\n".join(t)
    plt.figtext(left+i*width,0.35,t, va="top", ha="left")

plt.show()
```

[image]